# how to pass data with view in method?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-view

I am comparing paths of two images set in imageview selected from internal storage with following code but the method 'generate' requires Intent data which when passed with view gives an error saying 'view' is never used eg. public void generate( View view, Intent data ). please provide solution, thank you.

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 101);// change request
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Select Picture"), 102); // change request code
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 101) {
            // Get the url from data
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if ((null != selectedImageUri) ) {
                // Get the path from the Uri

                String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                Log.i(TAG, "Image Path : " + path);
                // Set the image in ImageView
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }else if(requestCode == 102){
            Uri selectedImageUri1 = data.getData();
            if ((null != selectedImageUri1)) {
                // Get the path from the Uri
                String path1 = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri1);
                Log.i(TAG, "Image Path : " + path1);
                // Set the image in ImageView
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2)).setImageURI(selectedImageUri1);
            }

        }
    }

}
public void generate( View view ){
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
    Uri selectedImageUri1 = data.getData();
    String path1 = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri1);
    if(path.contentEquals(path1)){
        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        String myString = "same images";
        myText.setText(myString);
    }
    else if(path1.length()%2==0) {
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        String myString = "repair completed";
        myText.setText(myString);
    }
    else{
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        String myString = "repair not completed";
        myText.setText(myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you are not using view anywhere in generate(). What exactly is the purpose?

Comment: You will get warnings (not errors) for unused variables.

Comment: if i dont pass it, it shows following error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method generate(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5673)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22513)

Comment: Ok. Now I get your point. You are using onClick from XML then?

If so, then your generate method can take ONLY ONE parameter which is View. If you want to pass data to it, use setOnClickListener from the activity/fragment class.

Comment: It would be a great help if you can tell me how to do that since i am late on my college project. Thank you

Comment: full code - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48482989/8863067

Comment: You can do
`((Button)findViewById(R.id.generate_button)).setOnClickListener(
new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
generate(data);
}
});`

I don't understand what you are looking for, where the data intent comes from.